# How do i write promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to write a promise but seems to be missing something. here is my code:

```
const myPromise = new Promise(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("getting here");
        return setinputs({ ...inputs, images: imageAsUrl });
      }, 100);
    });
    myPromise
      .then(() => {
        console.log("getting here too");
        firebase.database().ref(`collection/${idNode}`).set(inputs);
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("all is set");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

if i run the program, the first part of the promise is executing but all `.then()` functions arent executing. how do i fix this?

Comment: It doesn't look like `myPromise` is getting resolved? You're using `setinputs` rather than using `resolve()`, and then `setinputs` in a `then`

Comment: how do i write that with resolve()?

Comment: I would recommend reading up on promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I'll drop this here if you want to read about promises: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/js-illustrated-promises-c87efb8d27a9

Comment: Is setInputs the setter returned by useState? I never knew it was returning something.

Comment: @jperl `useState` always returns the state and a setter function?

Comment: If you want to trigger an action once the the variable has been set, you'll do that in useEffect(). Also, why the need for setTimeOut()?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I mean the setter returning something. I know that useState returns the state and a setter function.

Comment: @jperl I think op is trying to demonstrate the `async` behavior with a `setTimeout` and he may miss-understood that returning the result may resolve the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve the promise, using `resolve()` and also return the promise from firebase so the next `.then` in the chain works properly.

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("getting here");
    // You have to call resolve for all `.then` methods to be triggered
    resolve({ ...inputs, images: imageAsUrl });
  }, 100);
});
myPromise
  .then((inputs) => {
    console.log("getting here too");
    // You have to return a promise in a .then function for the next .then to work properly
    return firebase.database().ref(`collection/${idNode}`).set(inputs);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("all is set");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

In this scheme, the promise callback has one (resolve) or two (resolve,reject) arguments.

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
   //do something 
   //resolve the promise:
   if (result === "ok") {
      resolve(3);
   }
   else {
      reject("Something is wrong");
   }
});

p.then(res => {
   console.log(res); // "3"
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err); //"Something is wrrong
 });
```

Of course, nowadays you can use async + await in a lot of cases.

Comment: But even with async await you sometimes have to write your own promise, right?

Comment: Yes, as in your case with a timer. You could also use a rxjs observable for that. Most of the time it's await (some async call) now.

Comment: Not my case ... 